# Are tgid and pid ever different for a process or lightweight process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process, thread

tgid and pid are the same concept for any process or for any lightweight process.

In `/proc/${pid}/status`, tgid and pid are distinct fields. Are tgid and pid ever different for a process or lightweight process?

Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/if-threads-share-the-same-pid-how-can-they-be-identified) has a good explanation when that can happen.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html It's just kernel name things a little bit weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When looking at `/proc/${pid}/status`, then the `Tgid:` and `Pid:` fields will always match, since they're the same for a process or for the main thread of a process.

The reason why there are two separate fields is that the same code is used to produce `/proc/${pid}/task/${tid}/status`, in which `Tgid:` and `Pid:` may differ from each other. (More specifically, `Tgid:` will match `${pid}` and `Pid:` will match `${tid}` in the file name template used above.)

---

The naming is a bit confusing, mainly because threading support was only added to the Linux kernel later on and, at the time, the scheduler code was modified to reuse the logic that used to schedule processes so it would now schedule threads. This resulted in reusing the concept of "pids" to identify individual threads. So, in effect, from the kernel's point of view, "pid" is still used for threads and "tgid" was introduced for processes. But from userspace you still want the PID to identify a process, therefore userspace utilities such as `ps`, etc. will map kernel's "tgid" to PID and kernel's "pid" to "tid" (thread id.)

Answer (score 3):

TGid and Pid are different for threads spawned from the process leader.

eg looking at my `polkitd` process:

```
% ps -Lp 2642                          
  PID   LWP TTY          TIME CMD
 2642  2642 ?        00:00:18 polkitd
 2642  2680 ?        00:00:00 gmain
 2642  2683 ?        00:00:30 gdbus
 2642  2685 ?        00:00:00 polkitd
 2642  2687 ?        00:00:00 JS GC Helper
 2642  2688 ?        00:00:00 JS Sour~ Thread
 2642  2692 ?        00:00:00 polkitd
```

If I look at process `2680`:

```
% egrep ^'(Tgid|Pid):' /proc/2680/status
Tgid:   2642
Pid:    2680
```